# Are you required to buy items when you choose the Legendary Object options at the village?

Tags: tokaido, tokaido-crossroads

The wording of the rules states that you must either peruse/buy the souvenirs or buy a legendary object, but what if you cannot afford the remaining legendary objects? To the letter of the rules, it would imply that you must only choose this option if you *can* buy a legendary object, so players should determine what's in the pile of unbought items (easily done) before making that an option. More hand-wavey, we could argue if someone mistakenly doesn't realize he can't afford any of the remaining items, then chooses to buy a legendary object and picks up the remaining cards, he simply is barred from buying anything or resorting to the souvenir option.

I tend to lean toward the more forgiving option which is if a player can't afford anything, he just goes to the souvenir shop especially since the list of cards is public info obtained simply by looking at the players' holdings which are exposed.

Comment: I'm not sure of the official ruling, but the way we've been playing it is that you don't have to buy anything, and you've essentially either wasted or turn or simply blocked another person from choosing that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [rules for Tokaido: Crossroads](http://www.funforge.fr/US/files/crossroads/Crossroads_Rules_US.pdf) on the Fun Forge site (emphasis mine)

> Now, when a Traveler stops at a Shop space, he **must** choose between:
>
> - Buying Souvenirs (basic game rules).
> - Acquiring a Legendary Object.

While the [base game rules](http://www.funforge.fr/US/files/tokaido/Tokaido_rules_US_LD.pdf) (Souvenirs Only) say

> The player draws the first 3 Souvenir cards from the pile and places them face up in front of him. He **can** then purchase one or more of these cards by paying the price indicated on each card.
>
> Note: A traveler **must** have at least 1 coin to stop in a Village, but
> he **is not required** to purchase any souvenirs

In the base game it is clearly possible for the player to end up with only Souvenirs they cannot afford, in which case they can purchase nothing, as well as simply choosing to purchase nothing.

It seems fairly clear that the player must first decide which of the two purchase options they will pursue, and having made that decision the other option is no longer available. Having made that choice the same rules would seem to apply in both cases: if there is nothing they can purchase, they are out of luck; even if they can purchase something, they don't have to.

Further, unless you're playing with the 2-3 player variant for Crossroads, all players have perfect knowledge of what Legendary Objects are available to purchase. There are 6, 2 each costing 1, 2, or 3 coins, and any purchased objects are visible in front of the player(s) that purchased them. In the variant where 2 cards are discarded, they will have perfect knowledge after looking at the Legendary Objects once, and the goal of that variation seems to be to slightly increase the risk/reward given the large number of stop opportunities with so few players.

Answer (score -1):

Peruse means to browse or to look at. So you can just go to the shop look at the souvenirs for sale there.

As mentioned by John this can be done to block another player but would be a bit of a wasted move.